Where to Put Research On Resume Meant For Industry Purposes?
I've been working as research assistant in a lab and I've been working on a project that I'm presenting at a conference in the future. I'm updating my industry resume currently, and under the experience category, I've listed my research assistant position as well as a brief description of what I've done for the lab. However, I can't help but want to also add my research project as it's own bullet point under my project section. Would it be a good idea to generalize my projects category to projects and research, and also put my research under there? If so, how can I avoid having too much overlapping info between my RA bullet point and research project/not have too little information underneath my RA bullet point?

It's kind of hard for us to answer here, since a CV should really be optimized holistically so no one heading is too thin or too overwhelming. You could try both approaches, show them to a few people and ask which one works better for them.
